# asp.net onMouseEnter to modify button's location

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, location, dom-events

I'm developing a card game with Visual Studio and aspx.

In the page Head tag I added a Javascript function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cardMouseEnter()
    { document.forms[0].bCard1.style.top -= 5; }
</script>
```

A card is represented by a `asp:ImageButton` whose position is absolute and whose style property looks like this in the .aspx page:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="bNCard1" runat="server" 
        style="position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 2px;  
        height: 98px; width: 73px;" ></asp:ImageButton>
```

In the load event of the code-behind file I added:

```
bCard1.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "cardMouseEnter()")
```

When I try to run the page and I place the mouse on the card I have a Javascript error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined.

And when I inspect the code this is what I can see in a aspx(dynamic) generated page:

```
<input type="image" name="bCard1" id="bNorth1" onMouseOver="cardMouseEnter()" src="SomeCard.jpg"
       style="border-width:0px;top: 3px; left: 2px; position: absolute; 
       height: 106px; width: 73px; font-size:1.4em;" />
```

I feel this is weird, since the dynamically generated page has a "style" property.
Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use document.getElementById() to get the element in question and .getAttribute() to get the style and setAttribute() to set it
2. I would strongly suggest you look into jquery for anything javascript http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

**Script:**

```
function cardMouseEnter(id)
{ 
    document.getElementById(id).style.top -= 5; 
}
```

**Code-behind:**

```
bNCard1.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "cardMouseEnter('" + bNCard1.ClientID + "')");
```

**Markup:**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="bNCard1" runat="server" 
        style="position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 2px;  
        height: 98px; width: 73px;" ></asp:ImageButton>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do: cardMouseEnter(this), and pass in the actual cotnrol?

Comment: Yes you can, I would personally do it with unobtrusive jQuery and be using MVC.

Comment: Rick's solution works for 'some' style properties, like border, but not for the top location. On the other hhand, cardMouseEnter(this) doesn't works. +1 for Rick, but I con't accept the solution since the style.top isn't recognized.

Comment: Native style properties has nothing to do with the solution, there are many ways to change style via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
<input type="image" name="bCard1" id="bNorth1" onMouseOver="cardMouseEnter(this)" ...>

<asp:ImageButton ID="bNCard1" runat="server" onmouseover="cardMouseEnter(this)" ...>
```

And you JS function:

```
function cardMouseEnter(ctrlToMove) { 
   ctrlToMove.style.top -= 5; 
}
```